# RDA firewalld exception?

Tags: mariadb, firewalld

I'm using CentOS-7 and configuring two servers to run *OTRS System*, but the *Database Server* Firewall "**Firewalld**" is dropping the *Application Server* requests for RDA "Remote Database Access".
Because when i stop the *firewalld service*, database is accessed successfully.
How can i make an exception for the RDA Process through the Firewalld?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I solved it. In the *Database Server* i added the **mysql** service instead of the protocol **RDA** to the *firewall rules* using the strong rule:

```
firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule 'rule family="ipv4" source address="$APPLICATION_IPV4_ADDRESS" service name="mysql" accept' --permanent`
```

Or you can simply open MySQL port for all IPs "not recommended" as follows:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=mysql --permanent
```

Best Luck,